# How to close auth session?

Tags: authentication, session, flask, cookies

I have auth system using cookies. How can I disable all 'old' sessions after changing password remotely? (Flask-login) Now my program changes password, but all sessions with old password are still active.

Comment: mean you want to empty previous session values?

Comment: Flask-login using only cookie to log you into your account and it is not connected to your password. If your account is stolen, it is impossible to disable it on other devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is also store a JWT with last used password version on this device and also store the same value on server. And before each request you should check if this verisons are the same.